# "Error: /run/airflow doesn't exist. Can't create pidfile." when using systemd for Airflow webserver

Tags: amazon-ec2, airflow, systemd, airflow-scheduler

I have configured my Airflow setup to run with systemd according to [this](https://github.com/apache/airflow/tree/master/scripts/systemd). It was great for a couple of days but it has thrown some errors that I can't figure out how to fix. Running `sudo systemctl start airflow-webserver.service` doesn't really do anything but running `airflow webserver` works (however, using systemd is needed for our purposes).

To understand what's the error, I run `sudo systemctl status airflow-webserver.service`, and it gives the following status and error:

```
Feb 20 18:54:43 ip-172-31-25-17.ec2.internal airflow[19660]: [2019-02-20 18:54:43,774] {models.py:258} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /home/ec2-user/airflow/dags
Feb 20 18:54:43 ip-172-31-25-17.ec2.internal airflow[19660]: /home/ec2-user/airflow/dags/statcan_1410009501.py:33: SyntaxWarning: name 'pg_hook' is assigned to before global declaration
Feb 20 18:54:43 ip-172-31-25-17.ec2.internal airflow[19660]: global pg_hook
Feb 20 18:54:43 ip-172-31-25-17.ec2.internal airflow[19660]: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/helpers.py:346: DeprecationWarning: Importing 'PythonOperator' directly from 'airflow.operators' has been deprecated. Please import from 'airflow.operators.[operat...irely in Airflow 2.0.
Feb 20 18:54:43 ip-172-31-25-17.ec2.internal airflow[19660]: DeprecationWarning)
Feb 20 18:54:43 ip-172-31-25-17.ec2.internal airflow[19660]: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/helpers.py:346: DeprecationWarning: Importing 'BashOperator' directly from 'airflow.operators' has been deprecated. Please import from 'airflow.operators.[operator...irely in Airflow 2.0.
Feb 20 18:54:43 ip-172-31-25-17.ec2.internal airflow[19660]: DeprecationWarning)
Feb 20 18:54:44 ip-172-31-25-17.ec2.internal airflow[19660]: [2019-02-20 18:54:44,528] {settings.py:174} INFO - setting.configure_orm(): Using pool settings. pool_size=5, pool_recycle=1800
Feb 20 18:54:45 ip-172-31-25-17.ec2.internal airflow[19660]: [2019-02-20 18:54:45 +0000] [19733] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
Feb 20 18:54:45 ip-172-31-25-17.ec2.internal airflow[19660]: Error: /run/airflow doesn't exist. Can't create pidfile.
```

The scheduler seems to be working fine, as verified after running both `systemctl status airflow-scheduler.service` and `journalctl -f`.

Here's the setup of the following systemd files:

**/usr/lib/systemd/system/airflow-webserver.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=Airflow scheduler daemon
After=network.target postgresql.service mysql.service redis.service rabbitmq-server.service
Wants=postgresql.service mysql.service redis.service rabbitmq-server.service

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/sysconfig/airflow
User=ec2-user
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/airflow scheduler
Restart=always
RestartSec=5s

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**/etc/tmpfiles.d/airflow.conf**

```
D /run/airflow 0755 airflow airflow
```

**/etc/sysconfig/airflow**

```
AIRFLOW_CONFIG= $AIRFLOW_HOME/airflow.cfg
AIRFLOW_HOME= /home/ec2-user/airflow
```

Prior to this error, I moved my airflow installation from root to home directory. Not sure if it would have affected my setup but putting it here in case it is relevant.

Can anyone provide any explanation for the error and how to fix it? I tried my best to configure systemd as closely as possible to what is instructed but maybe I'm missing something?

**Edit 2:**

Sorry, I pasted the wrong code. So this is my code for airflow-webserver.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Airflow webserver daemon
After=network.target postgresql.service mysql.service redis.service rabbitmq-server.service
Wants=postgresql.service mysql.service redis.service rabbitmq-server.service

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/sysconfig/airflow
User=ec2-user
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/airflow webserver --pid /run/airflow/webserver.pid
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5s
PrivateTmp=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I encountered this issue too and was able to resolve the issue by providing runtime directory parameters under `[Service]` in the `airflow-webserver.service` unit file:

```
[Service]
RuntimeDirectory=airflow
RuntimeDirectoryMode=0775
```

I was not able to figure out how to get it to work with `/etc/tmpfiles.d/airflow.conf` alone.

Comment: @chorbs, could you please provide more detail on why this worked for you?

Comment: @Newskooler this is my first time using systemd so I am by know means expert but I assume that this tells systemd to create the dir /run/airflow with permissions 0775, and that when you don't specify this, the directory won't be created, or won't be created with sufficiently permissive permissions

Comment: That's exactly what it does. It makes the `/etc/tmpfiles.d/airflow.conf` redudnent. I don't know why it was not added in the airflow repo like this...

Comment: i added the runtimeDirectoryMode to 775,but still getting the same Error

Comment: did you also add `RuntimeDirectory`?

Answer (score 1):

The config file `/etc/tmpfiles.d/airflow.conf` is used by `systemd-tmpfiles-setup` service at boot. So, a server restart should create the /run/airflow directory. It's not possible to just restart this service as per https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/8684.

As suggested at the above link, after copying `airflow.conf` to `/etc/tmpfiles.d/`, just run `sudo systemd-tmpfiles --create` and `/run/airflow` should get created.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are running the scheduler and not the webserver:

`ExecStart=/bin/airflow scheduler`

You might want to do something like:

`ExecStart=/bin/airflow webserver -p 8080 --pid /run/airflow/webserver.pid`

Maybe you just copy pasted the wrong file, do share the correct one in that case (airflow-webserver.service) so we can help you troubleshoot this.

Comment: Sorry about that, I pasted the wrong code. I updated it above